# Object Creation using NewInstance()

Tags: java, object

I am beginner in java starting from basics, came across different ways of creating objects in java. What is the use in creating object with NewInstance() of Class or Constructors Class. What makes it different from objects created with New Keyword. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: There is no difference, and there's not a good reason to use `newInstance()` when you know the class you're constructing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It allows you to create instances of classes without knowing about them at compile time. This can be useful for frameworks or libraries.

Here's a toy example, where the library can inject its data into your class when it creates an instance:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class Eg {
    // library classes
    public interface Thing {

    }
    public static class ThingFactory {
        public static <T extends Thing> T create(Class<T> yourThingClass) throws InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
            for (Constructor c : yourThingClass.getDeclaredConstructors()) {
                if (c.getParameterCount() == 1 && c.getParameters()[0].getType() == String.class) {
                    return (T) c.newInstance("foo!");
                }
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Thing implementations must declare a constructor which takes a single String");
        }
    }

    // your classes
    public static class MyThing implements Thing {
        private final String s;
        public MyThing(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }

        public String getS() {
            return s;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        System.out.println(ThingFactory.create(MyThing.class).getS());
    }
}
```